# Ambiguities with Twilio Product Usage Summary

Tags: twilio

Here's what I see on my (free trial) Product Usage Summary:

[image: Twilio Product Usage screenshot]

I get what "PROGRAMMABLE VIDEO" and "PROGRAMMABLE VOICE" are, and I can see the usage detail.

**However what are the other items? What does "PV" means? Where can I find pricing references for these items?**

Also I don't understand how the total amount is computed. I would expect it to be the sum of the items in the last column, but this is clearly not the case.

**Are line 4 to 8 breakdowns of line 3? What is the underlying logic of this layout?**

Comment: In what way is this a programming question?

Comment: Good point. Do you know where else I should ask this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Product Manager here; I work on Video. It looks like this is actually a bug in the layout of the display--we're working on getting this fixed ASAP.

Your PV Room Participant US1 usage is the relevant item for understanding your Video bill--from your screen shot, it looks like you've consumed 37 Participant Connections in Twilio's US1 region, for a total of $0.37 of Video costs.

The other line items are actually intended to be aggregations of your usage. PV Room Participants aggregates all your Participant connections across all regions, and PV Rooms rolls up all those details into a single line.

The Rooms Hours item should not be displayed, and does not affect your bill in any way.

Apologies for this issue. We'll have it corrected shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

PV in this case appears to be constituent parts of Programmable Video.

Rooms is part of the API and [how Programmable Video is priced](https://www.twilio.com/video#pricing). I do agree though, it's not particularly clear and I have passed this question on to the team as feedback.

As you asked where you could ask a question like this, you are always welcome to get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who can help you out with this sort of query.